# KIVY: AsyncImage widget resizing issue within a RecycleView

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'll start with a little contextualization before explaining my issues.

I implemented a RecycleView widget that contains a RecycleBoxLayout whose default_size is dynamic (based on its parent's size). I believe this is needed (I'm probably wrong) because my app will be used on a wide variety of devices and I'd like my RV to contains an average of 4 PlaylistItem. Here the code inside the .kv file:

```
RecycleView:
    id: rv
    scroll_type: ['bars', 'content']
    scroll_wheel_distance: dp(114)
    viewclass: 'PlaylistItem'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, (self.parent.height / 4 - dp(80)) if self.parent.height / 4 > dp(60) else dp(60)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: dp(20)
        padding: dp(20)
```

Now let's take a look at the code for the PlaylistItem viewclass:

```
<PlaylistItem@BoxLayout>:
    created_time: ''
    description: ''
    id: ''
    image_url: ''
    name: ''
    owner: ''
    updated_time: ''
    playlist_name: ''

    MDCard:
        AsyncImage:
            size_hint_x: .2
            size: self.texture_size
            source: root.image_url
            mipmap: True

        BoxLayout:
            orientation:'vertical'

            MDLabel:
                text: root.playlist_name
                theme_text_color: 'Secondary'
                font_style:'Title'     
            MDSeparator:
                height: dp(1)
            MDLabel:
                text: 'Body'
                theme_text_color: 'Primary'
```

So, I'd like to keep the ratio of the image inside the AsyncImage widget. I'd like this image's width to take 20% of its parent widget. And finally I'd like the AsyncImage's size to be equal to its image's (texture) size. The code above does that BUT depending on the window's size, the image's height is not always equal to its parent's height (the result is not pretty uh). When I try:

```
AsyncImage:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.parent.height
    source: root.image_url
    mipmap: True
```

the image's height is always good (equal to the MDCard height) but the AsyncImage's width can become very large. Here's a picture so you better understand:

[image: Kivy's AsyncImage widget resize issue]

The only workaround I can think about is:

```
<PlaylistItem@BoxLayout>:
    created_time: ''
    description: ''
    id: ''
    image_url: ''
    name: ''
    owner: ''
    updated_time: ''
    playlist_name: ''

    # I ADDED THIS # <----------------------------------
    size_hint_y: None
    miminum_height: self.minimum_height

    MDCard:
        AsyncImage:
            size_hint_x: .2
            size: self.texture_size
            source: root.image_url
            mipmap: True
```

This is not working. I believe that at the time of init the texture has not loaded yet, thus self.minimum_height is None. I'm not sure about that. Hope someone could help.

Bonus detail: I know for sure that all my raw images have 480px height

Thanks a lot for your attention and sorry for the long post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atis on the #kivy IRC channel found the solution. One should simply use image_ratio!:

```
AsyncImage:
    size_hint: None,None
    size:self.image_ratio*root.height,root.height
    source: root.image_url
    mipmap: True
```